# Updating more than one column in Slick 3.x

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

In the example below it shows how to update a single column PRICE, first selecting a row and then updating it:

```
val q = for { c <- coffees if c.name === "Espresso" } yield c.price
val updateAction = q.update(10.49)

// Get the statement without having to specify an updated value:
val sql = q.updateStatement

// compiles to SQL:
//   update "COFFEES" set "PRICE" = ? where "COFFEES"."COF_NAME" = 'Espresso'
```

But what if I need to update three columns? is it possible with this approach?

**UPDATE**

These are the database classes

```
class OlapDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Olap](tag, "olap_queries") {

  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def descrip = column[Option[String]]("descrip")
  def notes = column[Option[String]]("notes")
  def mdx = column[String]("mdx")
  def folderSk = column[Int]("folder_sk")
  def lastUpdateUser = column[Option[String]]("last_upd_user")
  def lastUpdateTS = column[Option[LocalDateTime]]("last_upd_ts")(localDateTimeColumnType)
  def version = column[Int]("version")

  def * = (sk, name, descrip, notes, mdx, folderSk, lastUpdateUser, lastUpdateTS, version )
     <>  ((Olap.apply _).tupled, Olap.unapply)
}

case class Olap ( sk: Int, 
                  name: String, 
                  descrip: Option[String], 
                  notes: Option[String], 
                  mdx: String,
                  folderSk: Int,
                  lastUpdateUser: Option[String],
                  lastUpdateTS: Option[LocalDateTime],
                  version: Int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by selecting all columns that should be updated:

- With for comprehension, using `yield`:

  ```
  val query = for { c <- coffees if c.name === "Espresso" } yield (c.price, c.name)
  val updateAction = query.update((10.49, "Cappuccino"))
  ```
- Without for comprehension, using `map`:

  ```
  val updateAction = coffees.filter(_.name === "Espresso").map(c => (c.price, c.name)).update((10.49, "Cappuccino"))
  ```

Those two actions will be translated to the following SQL query:

```
update "COFFEES" set "PRICE" = ?, "COF_NAME" = ? where "COFFEES"."COF_NAME" = 'Espresso'
```

Comment: I'm getting the following errors when I try to use the `map` option: `◾No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List). Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]]) Unpacked type: T Packed type: G`

Comment: second error: `◾not enough arguments for method map: (implicit shape: slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel, (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]]), T, G])slick.lifted.Query[G,T,Seq]. Unspecified value parameter shape` The * projection is fine as the database class compiles with no errors

Comment: You haven't provided your table definition in the question, so I assumed that you're using the one from Slick docs. Since you have a different table definition, you should edit your question and provide it as well.

Comment: you're right, my apologies. I updated the answer with the database classes. I need to update the name, lastUpdateUser and lastUpdateTS. I think the problem is the lastUpdateTS that is not a type directly supported by Slick

Comment: During the update of `lastUpdateUser` and `lastUpdateTS` you should wrap your new values inside `Some`, becuase those columns are represented by an `Option[T]`. So you would have something like: `map(c => (c.name, c.lastUpdateUser)).update(("New name"), Some("Updated user"))`

Comment: Still get an error, sorry. My attempt: `.map(o => (o.name, o.lastUpdateUser, o.lastUpdateTS)).update(("my name"), Some("user1"), Some(LocalDateTime.now())) ` Note that the problem is the DateTime field as this works fine if I omit it in the update.

Comment: the error: `◾No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List). Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]]) Unpacked type: T Packed type: G`

Comment: second error: `◾not enough arguments for method map: (implicit shape: slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel, (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]]), T, G])slick.lifted.Query[G,T,Seq]. Unspecified value parameter shape.
`

Comment: We should avoid discussion in the comments and since the problem is not related to the original question, I think you should create a separate question. You should provide `localDateTimeColumnType` there, because you haven't posted it anywhere and your error cannot be reproduced.